# 18.04 - How to disable temporary/privacy IPv6 addresses?

Tags: networking, 18.04, ipv6, netplan

I have 18.04 installed and I'm using it as jump box to reach other things.

Some of the things I need to access are only reachable via IPv6 and expect me to connect from a specific IPv6 address so my box has a static IPv6 address configured.

For some reason, I can't seem to prevent Ubuntu from generating and preferring privacy IPv6 addresses. This means that when I try to connect to other things, I appear to come from the wrong IPv6 address.

I've configured Netplan with a static IPv6 address (example address shown - I'm not really using that)

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens192:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [192.168.212.152/25, '2001:0db8:85a3:0000::98/128']
      gateway4: 192.168.212.129
      nameservers:
        search: ['mydomain.local']
        addresses: [192.168.212.141, 192.168.212.142, '2001:0db8:85a3:0000::8d', '2001:0db8:85a3:0000::8e']
```

I have sysctl configured to not use IPv6 privacy addressing in /etc/sysctl.d/10-ipv6-privacy.conf:

```
# IPv6 Privacy Extensions (RFC 4941)
# ---
# IPv6 typically uses a device's MAC address when choosing an IPv6 address
# to use in autoconfiguration. Privacy extensions allow using a randomly
# generated IPv6 address, which increases privacy.
#
# Acceptable values:
#    0 - don’t use privacy extensions.
#    1 - generate privacy addresses
#    2 - prefer privacy addresses and use them over the normal addresses.
net.ipv6.conf.all.use_tempaddr = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.use_tempaddr = 0



$ sysctl net.ipv6.conf.ens192.use_tempaddr
net.ipv6.conf.ens192.use_tempaddr = 0
```

I'm still getting a temporary IPv6 address:

```
$ ip -6 addr
2: ens192: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
    inet6 2001:0db8:85a3:0000:20c:29ff:fede:fa42/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
       valid_lft 2591895sec preferred_lft 604695sec
    inet6 2001:0db8:85a3:0000::98/128 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fede:fa42/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I can delete the privacy address or set it as deprecated but it re-appears whenever I netplan apply or reboot.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: That's not a privacy address, it's a SLAAC modified EUI-64 address.

Comment: Ah, ok. So that would explain why the sysctl privacy settings have no effect. Next question then is how to tell the OS not to prefer the SLAAC address.

Comment: To be clear: You do not want to use the static address that SLAAC already provided you, and you want to manually set up one of your own? You probably already know this isn't a good idea, and isn't even necessary, right?

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do. 2001:0db8:85a3::98 is a lot easier to communicate and document than 2001:0db8:85a3:0000:20c:29ff:fede:fa42. The EUI-64 address is also only pseudo-static

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. 
I first tried to disable ipv6 autoconf and accept_ra in sysctl.conf

```
# sysctl -p
net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra = 0
net.ipv6.conf.lan.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.lan.accept_ra = 0
net.ipv6.conf.wan.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.wan.accept_ra = 0
```

But that did not change anything.
Since netplan has some timing problems I disabled accept_ra in netplan yaml file.

/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml

```
addresses:
- xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/24
- xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::xx/64
dhcp4: false
dhcp6: false
accept-ra: false
```

Comment: If you disable RA then you must also specify the gateway address.

Comment: I'm not sure where, but I saw that setting accept-ra: false is not recommended, but it was the only way I found to use netplan and have automatic IPv6

Comment: Just FYI: you don't need to explicitly disable DHCPv6 since the RAs tell the device whether to use it or not. Just setting "accept-ra: false" does the trick

Answer (score 0):

Put "accept-ra: false" under the interface configuration in your .yaml-file.

Comment: The answer works BUT since I'm getting downvotes all the time I thinks I should add that putting "autoconf 0" may work as well, at least when you are using "classic" "/etc(network/interfaces" configuration file.