# Set static IPv6 and disable IPv6 Autoconf

Tags: networking, 18.04, ipv6

I'm trying to replicate a DigitalOcean VM on my home network. They are using a static IP configured in `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml`. It has stuff for IPv4, and v6 and works how I want it to. My home VM with default 18.04.2 has only the following:

```
# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    ethernets:
        ens33:
            dhcp4: true
    version: 2
```

I created `/etc/netplan/99-ipv6.yaml` with appropriate settings and that adds the static IP with the right prefix, gateway, and DNS. I tried with `dhcp6: false` in both this file and the above mentioned file to no effect.

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        ens33:
            addresses:
            - 2607:f2c0:beef:beef::200/64
            gateway6: 2607:f2c0:beef:beef::1
            match:
                macaddress: 00:re:al:ma:ca:dd:re:ss
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                - 2001:4860:4860::8888
                - 2001:4860:4860::8844
                search: [mydomain.net]
```

How do I disable the auto configured IPv6 address? It is a proper address with my assigned prefix, but I only want the static address. Much of what I have seen here disables IPv6 all together, or doesn't use the 18.04 modern conventions for changes. Others mention `/etc/sysctl.conf`, but by default everything in that file is commented out, so I'm not sure what is necessary.

Below is the output from `ip a`:

```
    inet6 routable-address/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
       valid_lft 86165sec preferred_lft 14165sec
```

Comment: Wait a minute, I don't see any of your IPv6 netplan configuration here?

Comment: Sure, I'll pop that in...not sure why I didn't include that.

Comment: I didn't notice this one earlier: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1106069/18-04-how-to-disable-temporary-privacy-ipv6-addresses?rq=1 . That said, I don't see what the solution actually was. I think the address I'm seeing is the SLAAC assigned address based on my DUID (that's what was in "routable-address" in my addition